# Send custom status code with Flask send_file

Tags: python, flask

flask send_file returns 200 status upon success by default. Is there any way to change that behavior? Let's say I'd like to return 201.

Answer (score 3):

You can always return a tuple where the first element is the response object, which in this case is the send_file return value, and where the second element is the status code, e.g:

```
return send_file(...), 201
```

This works with any kind of response (strings, jsonified things, etc.).